# How to synchronize spring data elasticsearch with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to keep data in ElasticSearch in sync with the data I have and maintain in MongoDB.

Currently I have a batch job that finds all the changed data and updates it in elastic search using Spring-Batch and Spring-Data-ElasticSearch.

This works, but I'm looking for a solution where every change is directly mirrored in ElasticSearch.

Comment: What is your first solution? What do you mean by "synchronize"?

Comment: Okay, my first solution. I will using spring batch running everyday get data from database and create index to elasticsearch. But I want, when insert data to database and create index to elasticsearch. I call that is synchronize.

Comment: rephrased the question. I hope I kept the intended meaning, rollback if not. Can you please confirm that this represents your actual question? I found the original version hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

give this a go
[mongo connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector)

have a read through this [5 ways to sync data](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/5-way-sync-data-from-mongodb-es-kai-hao)